# How can I install ssh2 in Windows_NT (Azure web service) to connect VM from web service?

Tags: php, web-services, azure, ssh, windows-nt

To make my question more clear, I'm breaking them into parts.

1. I have created webpage in Microsoft azure using app service {http://####.azurewebsites.net}
2. I have created virtual machine linux (Ubuntu) platform
3. Both the service (web and vm) are in the same account (####@outlook.com).

Now, I want to connect **web service** with **vm**. I have seen solutions connecting using ssh2 in php codes as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799799/ssh-connection-to-a-remote-server-using-php).

I tried this in my local system (ubuntu). It was working fine. 
Now I want to connect to vm from web service. For this purpose how can I install ssh2 in webservice provided by azure.
I have logged into azure web service via ftp using terminal. [image] It shows **remote system is Windows_NT**.

How can I install ssh2 into webservice so that I can access vm from webservice.

Any help appreciated. Thank You

Comment: You may check this thread and see if that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434405/how-can-an-azure-web-site-reach-an-azure-hosted-virtual-machine?rq=1

Comment: Thank you @Ashok. I have seen this. This is again a paid service [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) . 
I am able to connect from my local system. Is there any way that I can use ssh2 in azure web service?

Comment: I am not sure my understanding is right, now web app on linux is supported, maybe you could try. https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/see-whats-new-for-azure-app-service-on-linux-preview/